# Delta load vs Wye load

Tags: three-phase

[image]

My answer for the first problem (Delta-Connected load)

[image]

The Solution manual answer matches my answer:
[image]

My answer for the second problem (Y-Connected load)

[image]

However, the Solution manual answer does not match my answer:

[image]

### Where is my mistake?

Source: Power Systems Analysis Publisher : McGraw-Hill Education; 1st edition (January 1, 1994) by John Grainger & William Stevenson ISBN-10 : 0070612935 ISBN-13 : 978-0070612938

Comment: Please take the time to type out your question and not paste images as Photon told you here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/567898/204153

Answer (score 0):

Your answer does not match because just by connecting the load differently, it changes its power consuption. So, it won't be the same \$8000 kW\$.

You could approach the solution by getting the phase current on the \$\Delta\$ connected load:

$$
I_{\phi,Load,\Delta} = \frac{S_{\Delta}}{3.V_{\phi,Load,\Delta}} = \frac{8\ MVA}{3\times13.8\ kV}
$$

Then, apply Ohm's Law to get the resistance of the load:

$$
R_{Load} = \frac{V_{\phi,Load,\Delta}}{I_{\phi,Load,\Delta}}
$$

Now, for question 3.14, you can solve it by recalculating the phase voltage (due to \$Y\$ connection), then find the line current on the load.

Then, calculate the new power consumption due to the new load connection:

$$
S_{Y} = 3.V_{\phi,Load,Y}.I_{\phi,Load,Y}=3.\frac{V_{\phi,Load,Y}^2}{R_{Load}}
$$

Then, you can finally apply your previously used methodology to find the new resistances.